# Insertar registros no existentes entre servidores

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando con localmente con SqlServer y tengo vinculado un servidor Oracle.
A mi tabla Sql necesito agregar solo los registros que no existan en ella de una consulta INNER de Oracle.

Agrego una imagen para describir mejor lo que comento, en el ejemplo los registros en color verde son los que no existen en mi tabla Sql, entonces solo busco agregar esos records.

[image: Ejemplo]

He creado este query pero de da error: returned message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" An error occurred while preparing the query "

```
INSERT INTO 
 Tbl1 (Comp, Size, Descr, Material_Type, Color, GCC)
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([Ext_CONEX],'
select distinct b.Comp
,b.Size
, a.Descr
,a.Material_Type
,a.Color
,a.GCC from tblb b
INNER JOIN tbla a
 ON
a.Compr=b.part_nbr
order by Comp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select Comp, Size From Tbl1
WHERE Tbl1.Comp = b.Comp)')
```

Alguna sugerencia para solucionar el problema.

Las tablas de mi servidor vinculado son actualizadas una vez al mes y puede tener algunos cientos de registros no existentes en mi tabla local.

Adjunto imagenes de la consulta en Oracle y el servidor vinculado en Sql Server:

[image: Oracle]
[image: LinkServer]

Pregunta meodificada para mejor entendimiento del foro y futuras preguntas relacionadas al tema.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos

DS

Comment: @gbianchi si el query esta probado directamente en Oracle y no tiene problemas.
Probe quitando el Order By y ahora tira error que la tabla o consulta no existe. Y creo es en el Where porque uno es el servidor local y el otro el sevidor vinculado.

Comment: entonces, no anda.. ni en oracle ni en ningun lado.. porque no podes vincular (que yo sepa) abiertamente sql server con oracle.. no funciona asi...

Comment: @gbianchi la consulta tal cual anda en Oracle dejame unos minutos y comparto la imagen

Comment: @gbianchi Listo acabo de agregar las imagenes una ejecutando la consulta en Sql Developer misma consulta que paso en el Open Query y el servidor vinculado en SqlServer. Nota: No puedo agregar los campos reales pero es exactamente la misma query.

Comment: @gbianchi lo que creo es que las tablas de los servidores no se conocen por ello en el Where creo deberia de pasar algun paramero, pero no se como hacerlo. Eso es lo que pienso.

Comment: ¿No sería mas conveniente que cada vez que se inserte (trigger) en Oracle se le notifique a la aplicación con SqlServer?

Comment: @Sal no es un insert en Oracle tengo acceso a ciertas vistas de Oracle esas tablas no tienen cambios durante un mes llegada cierta fecha limpian todas las tablas (vistas) y las recrean de nuevo con todos los datos pueden existir cientos nuevos o no

Comment: Ahhhhh para... vos estas parado en sql server.. le decis que ejecute un query en oracle.. pero tu where, incluye una tabla de sql server.. pero Oracle, no sabe como llegar a ese sql server... esto, sinceramente, parece el colmo de la complicacion!!!!!... obviamente te va a dar error, porque manda a ejecutar toda esa parte a Oracle.. no distingue, esto es de aca, esto de alla!!!!... yo haria esto de otra forma.. la voy a reabrir, pero especifica bien bien el problema... tal vez tenga alguna especie de solucion que desconozco...

Comment: @gbianchi específicamente no se que es lo que no entiendes ya comenté que las tablas no se conocen y que en el where es donde yo veo el problema se me ocurre pasar parámetros entre servidores como no lo se y no sé si es posible pasarlo en el Open query

Comment: @gbianchi dos bases de datos diferentes Oracle y SQL yo estoy en SQL quiero agregar a mi tabla SQL solo  los registros que no existen de las tablas de Oracle el servidor Oracle lo tengo vinculado en mi SQL.

Comment: No arreglaste tu pregunta.. y todo lo que me estas comentando, es tu pregunta, y no esta en tu pregunta!!!! yo como voy a saber que una de las tablas del where esta en sql server, y la otra en oracle??? lo que esta pasando, es que sql server le manda el query a oracle, y oracle no puede ejecutarlo porque hay pedazos de ese query que no estan en oracle!!!!! deberias mandarle parametros, o mandarle la lista de cosas que faltan, o mucho mejor, usar fechas u otro metodo y traer todo de ahi en adelante.. este metodo, cuando la tabla crezca, va a ser muy malo....ç

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas mostrando 5930 filas aprox. Por tanto la solución más simple es:

Crear una tabla temporal. Traer todas las filas de la consulta del servidor vinculado. E insertar si no existen en la tabla final.

```
Drop table if exists #ExternaltblComp;
CREATE TABLE #ExternaltblComp
             (
             comp          int
           , size          int
           , Descr         varchar(max)
           , Material_Type varchar(max)
           , Color         int
           , GCC           int
             );

Insert into #ExternaltblComp
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([Ext_CONEX],'
        select distinct b.Comp
            , b.Size
            , a.Descr
            , a.Material_Type
            , a.Color
            , a.GCC 
            from tblb b
            INNER JOIN tbla a
             ON a.Compr=b.part_nbr
            ');

INSERT INTO 
 Tbl1 (Comp, Size, Descr, Material_Type, Color, GCC)
 Select * from #ExternaltblComp b
 where not exists (
    select * from Tbl1 
    where tbl1.comp = b.comp
    );
```

Cosas a retocar. **Los tipos de datos de la tabla temporal** tienen que ser del mismo **tipo y tamaño** que lo que venga del servidor vinculado.

Dado que estás usando un distinct y por tanto no serán filas únicas, porque la columna `Comp`, claramente no es una primary key, como determinar que una fila no se debe de insertar, tendrás que hacerlo en el not exists en la parte del `where tbl1.comp = b.comp`, que me parece que no es único. Supongo que habra que comparar más columnas.

Al no tener la definición de las tablas ni ningún detalle, de como son los datos, ni en origen ni en destino, no se te puede aconsejar la creación de ninguna clave o indice que facilite la búsqueda para no tener que leer un montón de datos de más. Pero dado que dices que se hace una vez al mes, puedes probar haber si el rendimiento es lo suficientemente bueno, para lo que intentas.

Comment: Gracias Javi me funciona tambien encontre otra forma de hacerlo en ambos casos tarda alrededor de 8 segundos en procesar los querys. Comparto la otra solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui la otra opción:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl1 (comp, size, Descr, Material_Type, color, GCC)
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([Ext_CONEX],'
    select distinct b.Comp
        , b.Size
        , a.Descr
        , a.Material_Type
        , a.Color
        , a.GCC 
        from tblb b
        INNER JOIN tbla a
         ON a.Compr=b.part_nbr
        ');
EXCEPT
 SELECT comp, size, Descr, Material_Type, color, GCC FROM Tbl1
```

Espero sea de utilidad.

Gracias y se puede cerrar esta pregunta.

Comment: que quiere decir cerrar la pregunta?